# how to make @api.depends trigger a function when another model's field changes

Tags: odoo-11

i'm new in odoo dev and i'm trying to make the field value 'recommanded_price' (from marketplace.marketplaceinfo model) change when 'formula' field changes (which is in the marketplace.marketplace model)

I used the @api.depends decorator but it doesn't trigger the function

Here's the essential of my code

```
class marketplace(models.Model):
_name = 'marketplace.marketplace'
_description = 'Marketplace'

formula = fields.Char('Formula')
product_ids = fields.One2many('marketplace.marketplaceinfo', 'mkp', 'Products')

class marketplace_info(models.Model):
_name = 'marketplace.marketplaceinfo'
_description = 'Information about a product marketplace'
mkp = fields.Many2one('marketplace.marketplace','Marketplace',ondelete = 'cascade',required = True,
help='Marketplace of this product'
)
product_tmpl_id = fields.Many2one(
'product.template', 'Product Template',
index=True, ondelete='cascade')
price = fields.Float('Price', default=0.0, digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'),
help="The selling price for a product within the marketplace")
recommonded_price = fields.Float('Recommended Price', compute='_compute_recommonded_price' ,default=0.0, digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'),
readonly = True, help="The recommended selling price for a product within the marketplace")

@api.depends('mkp.formula')
def _compute_recommonded_price(self):
#do something
```

Answer (score 0):

#### @api.depends

This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is altered by ORM or changed in the form:

```
@api.depends('name', 'an_other_field')
def afun(self):
pass
```

Other then you can use another decorator

#### @api.onchange

This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form:

```
@api.onchange('fieldx')
def do_stuff(self):
   if self.fieldx == x:
       self.fieldy = 'toto'
```

Difference :
In previous sample self corresponds to the record currently edited on the form. When in on_change context all work is done in the cache. So you can alter RecordSet inside your function without being worried about altering database. That’s the main difference with @api.depends

REF : [enter link description here](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-depends)

Comment: but that's what I did, except that the field I want to specify in the decorator is a field from another model,
can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: mkp.formula - i think this is was not field

Comment: mpk is a Many2one field and its model has a formula field in it, so the path should be mpk.formula